# MySQL: sorting based on another join table that doesn't always have matching values

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

Here is the user case I have:

There are agencies that can have one or several locations.
They can buy a subscription for each location and for a ranking (a ranking is an integer between 1 and 5). So, an agency can have several subscriptions (up to one for each location)

Here are the tables:

```
agency: id, name
location: id, name
agency_location: agency_id, location_id
subscription: id, agency_id, location_id, ranking
```

So far so good, pretty straightforward.

Then I want to display all the agencies for a given location (say, location_id = 9), and order them by ranking for this location (knowing that some agencies won't have a subscription - i.e. no ranking, and should come after the ones who do have a subscription).

I've tried all sorts of SQL statements but can't seem to figure it out...

For example this:

```
SELECT * FROM {agencies}
LEFT JOIN subscription ON subscription.agency_id=agency.id
ORDER BY (subscription.ranking IS NULL) ASC, subscription ranking ASC
```

Will return all agencies, with the ones that have a subscription at the top ordered by their ranking.

But, 
1) it returns duplicate values if the agency has several subscriptions, and 
2) it doesn't take into account the location

Any clues would be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON s.agency_id = a.id
WHERE s.location_id = 9 ORDER BY s.ranking ASC
```

This query will give you the sorted by `ranking` agencies list in some location = 9. Agencies with no subscriptions will go below, because their ranking will be `NULL`. But the result of this query may contain duplicates when agency has more than one subscription.

You have to do `group by` over result, something like

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM agencies a
  LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON s.agency_id = a.id
  WHERE s.location_id = 9 ORDER BY s.ranking ASC
) as tempTable GROUP BY a.id
```

Or you can make result as tempTable and `left join` agencies table again and then `group by`. Try this yourself, I hope you got main idea. good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the tip, that's much appreciated. I think it's not quite right, however, as the agencies that have no subscription will appear first (that's why in my example I had to add the (subscription.ranking IS NULL) part

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the solution:

```
SELECT a.* FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN subscription s ON s.agency_id=a.id AND s.location_id=[some_id]
ORDER BY (s.ranking IS NULL) ASC, s.ranking ASC
```

The key was to add "AND s.location_id=[some_id]" in the LEFT JOIN statement. It both returns the ranking only for this location, and avoid duplicates record since there is only one ranking per location.